# Angular.js - Not understanding why my controller function isn't firing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

This is taken from Jason Watmore's tutorial on building an Angular.js modal window: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/13/angularjs-custom-modal-example-tutorial

This is a separate file called index.controller.js that houses just this controller.

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Home.IndexController', Controller);

    function Controller(ModalService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.openModal = openModal;
        vm.closeModal = closeModal;

        function openModal(id){
            ModalService.Open(id);
        }

        function closeModal(id){
            ModalService.Close(id);
        }
    }

})();
```

I have tried porting this to my app.js file within a controller called screeningsController, like this:

```
app.controller('screeningsController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){

    // this is a test function
    $scope.popup = function() {

    // assign a message to the $scope
    $scope.message = 'Hello World!';

    // use the $log service to output the message in a console
    $log.log($scope.message);

    };

    // this is the function that was ported over
    function Controller(ModalService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.openModal = openModal;
        vm.closeModal = closeModal;

        function openModal(id){
            ModalService.Open(id);
        }

        function closeModal(id){
            ModalService.Close(id);
        }
    }

}]);
```

The first function is just a test to see if the controller is able to be reached and working (it is). The second function "Controller" does not work. Dreamweaver throws the error, "'Controller' is defined but never used." This doesn't throw any errors in the browser console, but the function doesn't do anything.

Here is a section of my screenings partial screenings.php, where these functions are called:

```
...
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div id='img_div' ng-click='popup()'>";
            echo "<img id='img_screenings' class='modal_img' ng-click=\"vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')\" src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
...
```

The first echo houses the test function, and the second echo houses the other function. This is exactly how that function is called in the tutorial code. For reference:

```
<img class="picture" ng-click="vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')" src="picture.png">
```

Given all that, is there any indication as to why the second function is not working in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original file used the `Controller` function as the actual controller:

```
.controller('Home.IndexController', Controller);
```

But you created your own controller, and then moved the entire `Controller` function *inside* your own. You just need to take the functions:

```
app.controller('screeningsController', ['$scope', '$log', "ModalService", function($scope, $log, ModalService){

    // this is a test function
    $scope.popup = function() {

    // assign a message to the $scope
    $scope.message = 'Hello World!';

    // use the $log service to output the message in a console
    $log.log($scope.message);

    };

    var vm = this;

    vm.openModal = openModal;
    vm.closeModal = closeModal;

    function openModal(id){
        ModalService.Open(id);
    }

    function closeModal(id){
        ModalService.Close(id);
    }

}]);
```

**Edit**: Now you are binding to your controller in 2 different ways (`$scope` and `this`). You might want to just pick one of those to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to not throw the error in Dreamweaver anymore. Still not firing the function though. I guess the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: How are you connecting the template to this controller? If you're using `ng-controller`, you need the `controllerAs` syntax: `ng-controller="screeningsController as vm"`. If you're using the router or a directive, you need a `controllerAs` property.

Comment: Are `$scope` and `this` basically the same thing?

Comment: If there is no `controllerAs` property, would that account for the test function firing and the other one not firing?

Comment: I think this answers my first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Comment: Yes you need `controllerAs` somewhere to bind directly to `this` which is the instance of the controller.

Comment: Or you can forget about `controllerAs` and attach your new functions to `$scope` instead of `vm`. In the template just remember to remove `vm.`

Comment: As far as `controllerAs` vs `$scope`, is one preferred over the other? Does one make more sense here than the other?

Comment: I see - this is starting to make a lot more sense now. I guess the `vm` is a variable for `this`

Comment: So I could sub `$scope` in place of `vm` and just drop the `vm` declaration altogether?

Comment: It's often preference, but `controllerAs` is nice because you don't have to inject `$scope` into your controller unless you need it for some other reason, you clearly see `vm.` in your templates, you don't encounter some edge case issues involving data-binding and the prototypal inheritance of scopes, etc. There are tons of resources you can check out on the web.

Comment: Yep! I'd say read up on the differences and just pick one. Mixing them up can get confusing.

Comment: In the tutorial code, he has this: `ng-click="vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')"` ..that doesn't look like a `controllerAs` call, though?

Comment: Somewhere in the tutorial there must be `controllerAs: "vm"`

Comment: Ah I see it.  Thanks.